# PHP 8.3 from source, mysqli.so not found

Tags: php, mysqli, ubuntu-20.04

I've compiled php8.3 from source in ubuntu 20.04 server.
The installation process is

```
./configure --prefix=/home/ubuntu/php8.3 --enable-zts --with-mysqli --disable-fileinfo --with-openssl --with-zlib --with-curl --enable-pcntl  --enable-mysqlnd
make -j4
sudo make install
```

I've copied **php.ini-production** to **/home/ubuntu/php8.3/lib/php.ini** and enabled **extension=mysqli** in it.
But when I run `/home/ubuntu/php8.3/bin/php -v` I get

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /home/ubuntu/php8.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20220830/mysqli (/home/ubuntu/php8.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20220830/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /home/ubuntu/php8.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20220830/mysqli.so (/home/ubuntu/php8.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20220830/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

I've checked **/home/ubuntu/php8.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20220830/** and inside I've only **opcache.so**

Output of is **/home/ubuntu/php8.3/bin/php -m**

```
[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
random
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

So the question is, where is mysqli.so? What I'm wrong?

Thanks to all

Comment: What if you comment out `extension=mysqli` in the ini file?

Comment: Shouldn’t `extension=mysqli` be `extension=mysqli.so`?

Comment: If I comment out extension=mysqli php doesn't find mysqli_connect.

Comment: No, if I use extension=mysqli.so it will search for mysqli.so.so

Comment: PHP 8.3? Do you mean the master branch of php-src? There's no PHP 8.3 yet

Comment: Yes the master branch, sorry